# How to add an additional Uno head to an existing Uno solution?

Tags: uno-platform

I can only find [commands](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-dotnet-new.html) how to create and build Uno solutions from scratch but nowhere how to add - for example an additional mobile head ? Neither Visual Studio templates offer it on such granularity.

`dotnet new unoapp-net6 -h` tells neither anything about such option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding Platforms to an Existing Project
If you have an existing Uno Platform project, and you have not selected all the platforms you need when creating the project, this guide will show you how to add new ones.

Considering that your project is called MyProject, and you want to add the Gtk project head:

1. In a separate temporary folder, create a new project using the Visual Studio 2022 or dotnet new templates, using MyProject for its name.
2. Unselect all platforms except Gtk in the platforms selection dialog
3. Once the project has been created, navigate to the new folder MyProject.Skia.Gtk
4. Copy this folder to the existing project structure, at the same level as the other platform folders
5. In Visual Studio, right-click on the Platforms solution folder, then select Add, Existing project
6. Save your solution

Your new platform project is now ready to be compiled.

[platform.uno](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/guides/how-to-add-platforms-existing-project.html)